# Do associated classes of a subclass inherit the superclass?

Tags: oop, inheritance, uml, class-diagram

I'm trying to understand how inheritance with association work between the superclass and its subclasses. Here are the classes with their relationships:

[image: Classes]

my question here if I created an object from class C, will it inherit also from class A as below? and why?

[image: Objects]

Comment: No. But if A would inherit from B (if the arrow would point down) then the second diagram would be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It won't inherit anything. `B` inherits from `A` so `C` will see a `B` with operations/attributes inherited from `A`.

If I (class `C`)  use a cleaning device `B` that inherited from `Sponge` (`A`) I will see/use a soft cleaning device. If `B` inherited from steel it would be steel wool. If inherting from sand it would be sand paper. All cleaning devices with different usability depending from where they inherit. But I wouldn't change in any way. Only the way I would "clean" things. (I know, a horrible example)

---

N.B. As @www.admiraalit.nl commented your object diagram does not match the class diagram.

Comment: Do you mean "If I (class C)..."  ?

Comment: Another example: A = File, B = Movie, C = Actor. A Movie is a special kind of File and inherits all features of File. Movies and Actors have a relationship: Actors play in Movies. But instances of File that are not also instances of Movie, do not have links with Actors.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Yes, sure :-) Thanks!